# c++ memory access violation

Tags: c++, class, access-violation

I am learning C++ and I am having quite a lot of trouble with my current assignment. I have completed a good amount of it so far. However I have been making very slow progress of late due to what I think is my poor understanding of what is going on behind the scenes.

What I am trying to do in the following code is:

- Get two separate values (Bullet damage). Done.
- Create a dynamic array. Done.
- Fill a part (that is the size of a modulus of a random number between 1 and 10) of said dynamic array with one value and the rest with the other in a random order. Here I am having trouble.
- Clean up the memory used by said dynamic array. Done.

The error I get is as follows:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00a323e3 in Class 3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0xcdcdcdcd.

I'm pretty sure that the error occurs when I try to set `ammoArray[i]` to a value. But I don't know why it's giving it to me, my code compiles fine. I played around with it a bit and in one case I got it to store the memory addresses of `bDamage` and `sDamage` and then print out the memory addresses of each element of the array. What I want it to do is store the values held by `bDamage` and `sDamage`.

*Now for my question:*

Why won't `ammoArray` store the values of `bDamage` and `sDamage` instead of the memory addresses of the array's elements? And How do I get it to store them?

Here is my Main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Ammunition.h"
#include "AmmunitionManager.h"
#include "Bullet.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include "Pistol.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "Point.h"
#include "Shell.h"
#include "Shotgun.h"
#include "WeaponManager.h"
#include "Weapons.h"

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    Ammunition amVar;
    AmmunitionManager *var = new AmmunitionManager();

    amVar.setBDamage(6);
    amVar.setSDamage(2);
    var->FillAmmoArray(amVar.getSDamage(),amVar.getBDamage());

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Here is the .h file of the class in question:

```
#ifndef AMMUNITIONMANAGER_H
#define AMMUNITIONMANAGER_H
#include "Point.h"
#include "Ammunition.h"

class AmmunitionManager
{
public:
    AmmunitionManager();
    AmmunitionManager(int,int);
    ~AmmunitionManager();

    void FillAmmoArray(int,int);
private:
    Ammunition Ammo;
    int **ammoArray;
};

#endif
```

Here is the .cpp file of the class in question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include "AmmunitionManager.h"
#include "Point.h"
#include "Ammunition.h"

using namespace std;

AmmunitionManager::AmmunitionManager()
{
}


AmmunitionManager::AmmunitionManager(int sDamage,int bDamage)
    :Ammo(sDamage,bDamage)
{
    cout << "Filling ammo reservoir." << endl;
    ammoArray = new int* [10];
}

void AmmunitionManager::FillAmmoArray(int sDamage,int bDamage)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int *holdS = &sDamage;
    int *holdB = &bDamage;
    if(ammoArray)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < 9;i++)
        {
            int randC = rand() % 2 + 1;
            if(randC == 1)
            {
                cout << "Was: " << ammoArray[i] << endl;//I am getting the error here.
                ammoArray[i] = holdS;
                cout << "Is: " << ammoArray[i] << endl;
            }
            if(randC == 2)
            {
                cout << "Was: " << ammoArray[i] << endl;//I am getting the error here.
                ammoArray[i] = holdB;
                cout << "Is: " << ammoArray[i] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

AmmunitionManager::~AmmunitionManager()
{
    *ammoArray = 0;
    if(ammoArray)
    {
        delete [] ammoArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're storing pointers to parameters. Never do that. Your ammo array should be an array of `int`, not of `int*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why won't ammoArray store the values of bDamage and sDamage instead of the memory addresses of the array's elements?

Because you said it should store addresses.
Here is a pointer to a pointer:

```
int **ammoArray;
```

and here is an array of pointers:

```
ammoArray = new int* [10];
```

> And How do I get it to store them?

By doing this instead:

```
int *ammoArray;
```

and this:

```
ammoArray = new int [10];
```

and adjusting `FillAmmoArray` accordingly.

The default constructor should look like this:

```
AmmunitionManager::AmmunitionManager()
  : ammoArray(nullptr)
{
}
```

The destructor should look like this:

```
AmmunitionManager::~AmmunitionManager()
{
    delete [] ammoArray;
}
```

And you should only call `srand` once.
It's usually done at the beginning of `main`.

Comment: Wow, that was a lot simpler than I thought. I'll make sure to remember this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you initialize `AmmunitionManager` with the default constructor:

```
AmmunitionManager *var = new AmmunitionManager();
```

In you default constructor you do nothing so `ammoArray` may contain any value.
It is better to initialize all the data to their default values:

```
AmmunitionManager::AmmunitionManager() : Ammo(), ammoArray(NULL/* or nullptr for C++11 */)
{
}
```

Now if you call for

```
var->FillAmmoArray(amVar.getSDamage(),amVar.getBDamage());
```

It will exit immediately since `ammoArray` is NULL.
Or probably you want to initialize `ammoArray` anyway, so the default constructor should have its initialization as well:

```
AmmunitionManager::AmmunitionManager() : Ammo()
{
    ammoArray = new int* [10];
}
```

Also `srand` should be called only once, so better to place this code

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

in the `main()` or any other module which is guaranteed to be executed only once.

In the destructor, there is no need to zero `*ammoArray=0`, it actually puts 0 at the first element of that array (and that's it), you anyway delete it. And imagine that `ammoArray` is NULL, accessing `*ammoArray` would cause another segmentation fault.

Also there is no need to check for `ammoArray` beibg NULL before deleting it. The standard allows to '`delete`' NULL pointers. `delete` will just return without doing nothing.

**General note**

It is better to use (safer and easier to maintain) [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/?kw=vector) instead of (dynamic) arrays and [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) instead of flat ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting any errors (VS2013). But the values stored are the addresses of sDamage and bDamage.

Did you properly use `AmmunitionManager(int sDamage,int bDamage)` as a constructor for creating the AmmunitionManager object? From what I'm seeing, you're not.

Apart from that, may I ask why you're using exotic constructs such as `**ammoArray` instead of e.g. a simple `vector<int>`? I'm guessing it's part of your assignment, but I'm asking just to make sure I'm not missing anything.

I called the object like this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    AmmunitionManager* tc = new AmmunitionManager(5,10);
    tc->FillAmmoArray(10,10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I was using the constructor properly. I _am_ required to use what you are calling "exotic constructs" unfortunately. However I added the parameters on the end of the new instance of `AmmunitionManager()` like you have done and suddenly it is executing a few of the `cout`'s that I put in.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit tricky answering without building and debugging, but the first thing that strikes me are: Why are you using pointers (`*`) to `int` throughout?

Why don't you just have the array as a pointer:

```
int *ammoArray;
```

and make the other `int`-instances (remove the pointers - `*` and the `address-of`'s (`&`))?

Regards

Comment: Not an answer - should really just be a comment.

Comment: @PaulR How isn't it an answer? It my suggestion on how to solve the problem. U think I should re-write the code for questioner?

Comment: It's two general comments in the form of questions/suggestions, neither of which addresses the major bugs in the code (see @AlexLop.'s answer).

Comment: @PaulR I see your point, Paul. AlexLop's answer points to the *real* problem (should have read the code more thorough :-$). I'm leaving the answer here as a suggestion, though, because I still think the pointers are an "issue".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @naltipar Actually I think it does in part. If you check the accepted answer it's basically what I suggested here. The strange thing is that the accepted answer doesn't mention what Alex Lop correctly pointed out, namely that his the code never initializes `ammoArray` with the default constructor. Even though setting it to `NULL` is an improvement, thereby avoiding the exception. If You read the post the question clearly is **Why won't ammoArray store the values of bDamage & sDamage instead of the memory addresses of the array's elements? And How do I get it to store them?** which I answered.